# Text input and button alignment

Tags: html, css, reset

Is there any way to align text input boxes with buttons without using a table? I tried using resets and clearing margins and padding. As you can see in the image below, the button is not aligned with the input element. Do I have to use tables to align them or is there any other method?
[image]

I am talking about how the button is indented compared to the text field. Code is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search users"/>
    <br>
    <input value="Search" type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your current html.

Comment: Can you put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
    display: block;
}
input {
    margin: 0;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/65UAD/)

## -- Edit --

```
input[type=text] {
    display: block;
}

input {
    margin: 1px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/65UAD/2)

Comment: Are you using Windows? I think it depends on OS too.

Comment: I don't think it does, but I am on Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, this is the default behaviour.

http://jsbin.com/icuyob/1/edit

```
<input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search users"/>
<br>
<input value="Search" type="submit"/>
```

Just remove the line break from your html, and the elements will align next to each other, even without any css.

Comment: I want a line break though.

Comment: I think he was talking about that little extra gap on the left of the button

Comment: Yes. I used a `<br>` tag for a reason.

Comment: how do you want them aligned? I thought you want them next to each other.